# Set of limits points of $\mathbb{Q}$ is non enumerable

Tags: real-analysis

Prover or disprove: that a countable set cannot have uncountable number of limit points

$\mathbb{Q}$ is countable the set of all limit points of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the derived set of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is not enumerable hence the statement is false 
Is my proof right?

Comment: right not wrong

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you

Comment: You have correctly disproved the claim (you should probably say that that is what you are trying to).

Comment: The title of your question and the statement of your question (what you are asked to "prove or disprove") have opposite conclusions. The title is right, the statement is wrong.

Comment: But is my proof right?

Comment: I have disproved the claim that a countable set cannot have uncountable number of limit points

Comment: How much confirmation do you need?